Problem to add spring-boot jar in the other spring project
I have a legacy Spring MVC where I'm trying to add a fat-jar made with spring-boot-starter that performs some operations with the database... That said, after successfully generating and executing the fat-jar, adding it as a dependency in the legacy project's pom, it now apparently starts loading the dependency settings, generating a context/mapping error
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/user] in DispatcherServlet with name...
I'm new to Spring, if you can help I would appreciate it in advance
Only when removing the jar does the main project work again
My Spring boot package
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


Why are you using the assembly plugin and not the regular spring-boot-maven-plugin? Next you cannot use a spring boot generated jar as a dependency, if you want you need to generate 2 artifacts as explained in the reference guide

Here is a sample to build a jar file that is usable as a dependency https://stackoverflow.com/a/78499980/6512438
